# ssh-add adds incorrect key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, jenkins, capistrano, ssh-agent

Background: I am trying to write a jenkins job which deploys a rails app using capistrano. As part of this, I need to add the ssh key which I have copied to the jenkins user's .ssh folder on that environment. I have correctly set the owner, group and permissions for both id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in that folder.

I am receiving the error `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user deploy@[server]`. Upon investigation, the following happens when I run the following commands as the jenkins user:

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

so far so good.

But the public key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is not the one returned by `ssh-add -L`

If I follow the same steps on my local machine, the correct key is added and I am able to ssh into the environment.

Why does ssh-add seem to add the wrong key (which I can't seem to find anywhere else on the system)?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ssh-add -L` on jenkins server you're probably seeing public key forwarded from your own machine via the "ssh agent forwarding" mechanism.

Try `ssh`ing to your jenkins server with the `-a` flag to disable ssh agent forwarding:

```
ssh -a <jenkins_server>
```